# Install Node 6.9 on Ubuntu Zesty 17.04

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, npm, angular-cli

I want to install a newest version of `NodeJS` on `Ubuntu Zesty 17.04`. But whether using apt-get or trying to download it from nodesource ppa, I always have the version 4.7.2.

Apt-get

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs npm
```

Node PPA

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo bash -
sudo apt-get update
apt-get install nodejs npm
```

Result

```
$> node -v
v4.7.2
```

How can I get the version 6.9 of NodeJS ?

Comment: Your installation instructions worked fine for me: `$ node -v
v6.11.2`

Comment: For me, in turn, they didn't. Weird.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I didn't succeed to install it via apt-get or nodesource ppa. However I solved the problem by installing Node manually by following these steps :

1. Remove the old version `sudo apt-get remove --purge node`
2. Download Node binaries from https://nodejs.org/en/
3. Extract the archive where you want `tar -xzf <ARCHIVE>.tar.gz -C <YOUR_FOLDER>`
4. Create a **node** symbolic link `ln -sf <YOUR_FOLDER>/bin/node /usr/bin/node`
5. Create a **nodejs** symbolic link `ln -sf <YOUR_FOLDER>/bin/node /usr/bin/nodejs`

*result :*

```
radouane@roufid:$ node -v
v6.10.2
```

I hope it helps !

Comment: Thank you for this answer. It is ridiculous how painful this was until I came across this solution.

Answer (score 11):

Best way is to use [n](https://github.com/tj/n). It is a node module that helps you to update and switch between node versions easily.

`npm install n --global`

`n list` will list all node versions.

If you want to switch to new version `6.10.2` use command
`n 6.10.2`

Comment: I have the following error : 

install : node-v6.10.2

Error : invalid version 6.10.2

Would you please help me to solve it ?

Comment: curl 7.52.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.52.1

Comment: And what about this `which head`

Comment: /usr/bin/head. I tried to find if there is a lib that conflict but it seems to be no.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142519/discussion-between-harikrishnan-and-radouane-roufid).

Comment: Unfortunately, using npm requires node.js in the first place which means I had to install the legacy version of node.js available in the Ubuntu repositories, use that to install `n` and then use `n` to install a more up-to-date version of node.js. This opened up a whole Pandora's box worth of problems involving setting up symlinks to the node.js version I want, not being able to remove the legacy version, … so I finally gave up and went with the manual install instead which worked right away. What a nightmare.

Comment: It is very convenient to install n without having installed node before with n-install https://github.com/mklement0/n-install.

Answer (score 0):

To install the NodeJS any version

```
# you can replace number 6 with new version
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo bash - 
sudo apt install nodejs
node -v
```