# I can not install the nodejs 6 on ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

At first I installed the node with terminal, with command
Update Package Manager

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Adding NodeJS PPAs

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -
```

Installing NodeJS and NPM

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

It works, but when I am looking version node, I see node v 4
Then I used google for search this problem and a found this topic
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43914369
There using a ln command for create symbolic link between two files

and used this instruction for manual install, but nothing happens, error appears and not installing 
[Look at this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhFyS.png)
Maybe I doing anything wrong?

Comment: I caught this several times on different machines. You can try this solution: https://askubuntu.com/questions/426750/how-can-i-update-my-nodejs-to-the-latest-version

Answer (score 0):

I tend to avoid using my operating system's package manager to install node. The easiest way to install node is [Node Version Manager](https://github.com/creationix/nvm).

Answer (score 0):

Yeah! The solutions found in official site
Of course link [Install node version 6](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions)

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
sudo apt-get install -y build-essential
```

but for this you need curl to be installed.

```
sudo apt-get update
```

To install curl: `sudo apt-get install curl`

[Here](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions)'s the link for this.

To upgrade node to latest version: https://askubuntu.com/questions/426750/how-can-i-update-my-nodejs-to-the-latest-version#480642